# How to extract HTML tags from the web page generated at runtime

Tags: php, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I am using a SimpleHTMLDOM parser to extract HTML data from web pages. But I came across websites such as [www.coursera.com](http://www.coursera.com) wherein the webpage is generated at runtime.

I need to know has anyone tried parsing such pages?

I am new to this field so some theory on this topic would help my understanding in parsing webpages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case its probably easier (though not always). The data being used to generate content is likely part of ajax requests you can sent a request to those ajax endpoints directly and parse the response from the endpoint.

Often this will be in JSON, which is quite easy to parse compared to HTML.

Comment: How can you be sure that some of the HTML is not generated directly on Javascript, not using AJAX ???

Comment: It certainly could be. But the data has to come from somewhere. Look for that source instead of trying to parse the end result.

Comment: you guys can go ahead and check the the source code of www.coursera.com

Comment: You are probably looking for this https://www.coursera.org/maestro/api/topic/list2

Comment: Datasage is right, the data is coming from json ajax calls. Don't look at the source though - look at the requests the site is making in your browser's network panel or a debugging proxy.

Comment: @datastage can u elaborate the process im new to this

Comment: @shailbenq Two parts really. You can use browser development tools to find the requests. Once you find the requests, you can download it like normal via `curl`  or `file_get_contents` as you probably are already. But instead of loading into it into the html parser, you would instead decode the result with `json_decode`. That will give you an array with all of the data.

Comment: @datasage But how can we get the data that is present on https://www.coursera.org/courses , because the coursera.org/maestro/api/topic/list2 will just fetch the information of universities providing the courses. Also i came across one of the sites that extracts data from coursera , http://www.class-central.com/initiative/coursera . I need to access the data similar to the above mentioned site. Can you please help me on this .

Comment: @shailbenq You will have to find the requests that provide the information you are looking for. They will show up in developer tools. The request will probably start with https://www.coursera.org/maestro/api

Answer (score 1):

John Resig wrote an HTML Parser.

> **[Demo](http://ejohn.org/apps/htmlparser/)**: http://ejohn.org/blog/pure-javascript-html-parser/

This can workout for you.